# javascript disable button conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come I get the alert's but the button doesn't enable after a negative is changed to a positive after updating the grand total from a select.
Here is the section that is not working:

```
    if ($('.grand_total').val() < 0) {
   $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
   alert('negative number found');

} else if ($('.grand_total').val() > 0) {
   $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
   alert('positive number found');
}
```

and here is the complete code:

```
 <script language="javascript">
 $(".add_to_total").on('change', function() {
var total = 0;
var grand_total = 0; 
$(".dynamic_row").each(function() {
    var row = $(this);

    var start_hour_am = parseFloat(row.find(".start_hour_am").val()) || 0;
    var start_minute_am = parseFloat(row.find(".start_minute_am").val()) || 0;

    var end_hour_am = parseFloat(row.find(".end_hour_am").val()) || 0;
    var end_minute_am = parseFloat(row.find(".end_minute_am").val()) || 0;        

    var start_hour_pm = parseFloat(row.find(".start_hour_pm").val()) || 0;
    var start_minute_pm = parseFloat(row.find(".start_minute_pm").val()) || 0;          

    var end_hour_pm = parseFloat(row.find(".end_hour_pm").val()) || 0;
    var end_minute_pm = parseFloat(row.find(".end_minute_pm").val()) || 0;

    total = ( (Number(end_hour_am) + (Number(end_minute_am))) - (Number(start_hour_am) + Number(start_minute_am)) + (Number(end_hour_pm) + Number(end_minute_pm)) - (Number(start_hour_pm) + Number(start_minute_pm)));
    row.find(".total").val(total);
    grand_total = Number(grand_total) + Number(total);  

}); 
    $("#grand_total").val(grand_total);


if ($('.grand_total').val() < 0) {
   $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
   alert('negative number found');

} else if ($('.grand_total').val() > 0) {
   $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
   alert('positive number found');
}  

 });
 </script>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Here is the html for the Grand total:

```
<input type="text" class="grand_total" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" data-role="none" value="0" size="3" readonly="true">
```

and here is the button which i'm trying to disable:

```
<button type="submit" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" data-icon="check" value="submit-value">Submit</button>
```

With Nick N's suggestion, still get the same problem with the button disable/enable.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(".add_to_total").on('change', function() {
    var total = 0;
    var grand_total = 0; 
    $(".dynamic_row").each(function() {
        var row = $(this);

        var start_hour_am = parseFloat(row.find(".start_hour_am").val()) || 0;
        var start_minute_am = parseFloat(row.find(".start_minute_am").val()) || 0;

        var end_hour_am = parseFloat(row.find(".end_hour_am").val()) || 0;
        var end_minute_am = parseFloat(row.find(".end_minute_am").val()) || 0;        

        var start_hour_pm = parseFloat(row.find(".start_hour_pm").val()) || 0;
        var start_minute_pm = parseFloat(row.find(".start_minute_pm").val()) || 0;          

        var end_hour_pm = parseFloat(row.find(".end_hour_pm").val()) || 0;
        var end_minute_pm = parseFloat(row.find(".end_minute_pm").val()) || 0;

        total = ( (Number(end_hour_am) + (Number(end_minute_am))) - (Number(start_hour_am) + Number(start_minute_am)) + (Number(end_hour_pm) + Number(end_minute_pm)) - (Number(start_hour_pm) + Number(start_minute_pm)));
        row.find(".total").val(total);
        grand_total = Number(grand_total) + Number(total);  

    }); 
        $("#grand_total").val(grand_total);


    //if (parseFloat($('.grand_total').val()) < 0) {
    //   $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    //   alert('negative number found');

    //} else if (parseFloat($('.grand_total').val()) > 0) {
    //   $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
    //   alert('positive number found');
    //}


    var total = parseFloat($('#grand_total').val());
    if(total < 0){
       $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
       alert('negative number found...');
    }
    else {
       $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
       alert('positive number found...');
    }     

});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
Ok looks like the issue is because the button is a jquery mobile generated button its not updating the state of the button when a negative value is found, If i refresh the whole form the button state then chnages. I tested this by setting the data-role to none so the submit button becomes a standard form button and the disable/enable functionality works.
Any ideas how i can get around this?

Comment: use like this pasreInt($('.grand_total').val()) and check

Comment: Are you sure your selector is right? Does #submit actually select the button you want to disable?
Try it in the chrome console

Comment: try use `attr` insead of `prop`

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var total = parseFloat($('.grand_total').val());
if(total < 0){
   $('#submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");
   alert('negative number found');
}
else {
   $('#submit').removeAttr("disabled"); 
   alert('positive number found');
}
```

---

**Jquery Mobile:** Don't refresh the whole form, but refresh just the button:

```
$('#submit').button('refresh');
```

---

**Please note:** that  I changed '#' to '.'. Dependent on your HTML you could also change this line:

```
 $(".grand_total").val(grand_total);
```

to:

```
$("#grand_total").val(grand_total);
```

Comment: Hi Nick N, I placed your code in and checked the selectors in the html, still not working, i get the alerts but nothing on the button. If the grand_total changes to a negative it does the alert but doesn't disable the button. Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited my answer, this should work. It has to do with that disabled should have the value 'disabled' and not true. If enabled, just remove the whole attribute.

Comment: Nick N see my above update, found out its to do with the button being a jquery mobile button. It will update the state only after a form refresh. So your original code does work, but the button doesn't update until a form refresh.

Comment: just refresh the button then, not the whole form, edited again

Comment: Thanks Nick N yes found that when searching around on here as well. I will award you as the correct answer, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing  `$('.grand_total').val()`
instead of `$('#grand_total').val()`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var total = parseInt($('.grand_total').val());
if(total < 0){}
else {}
```